# Question: Databinding not working with runtimeOnly gradle dependncies

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding

Hoping someone can explain why data binding per **module** seems not work (returns null) when a specific module/s are declared as `runtimeOnly` vs when it's declared as `implementation`.

**e.g.**

Say I've got some feature modules which I want to include or exclude (similar to dynamic feature modules) except I'm not using that right now for other reasons I will not go into, this is more of an experiment. So the idea was to have multiple components detached from the main application that are only made available at runtime, so in other words virtual no coupling between app and any of the add-on features and this works fine until I add data binding into the mix, crashing with a `*Binding cannot be null`.

[image: Application level build.gradle]

The only way I've gotten this setup to work is by switching back from `runtimeOnly` to `implementation` and from what I know so far the difference between `runtimeOnly` and `impelentation` are on the [gradle website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html):

[image: Gradle configurations]

So my question is why does this happen, does enabling databinding in modules require the module to be configured with `implementation`? Or perhaps I'm doing it all wrong and have misunderstood the purpose of `runtimeOnly`.

> Thank you in advance, and apologies if the question is not comprehensive enough

Answer (score 0):

- **implementation:** mostly we use implementation configuration. It hides the internal dependency of the module to its consumer to avoid accidental use of any transitive dependency, hence faster compilation and less recompilation.
- **runtimeOnly:** when we want to change or swap the behaviour of the library at runtime (in final build).

In the case of runtimeOnly, you need two dependencies one which will help you to access the code at compile-time and one which will replace/use at runtime.

**Example of Runtime:**

SLF4J is one of the best examples of runtimeOnly, where we will use slf4j-api as implementation configuration and implementation of slf4j-api (like slf4j-log4j12 or logback-classic, etc) as runtimeOnly configuration.

I have created a **[post](https://medium.com/@gauraw.negi/how-gradle-dependency-configurations-work-underhood-e934906752e5)** with an in-depth understanding of each one with **[Working Example: source code](https://github.com/GaurawNegi/Examples-gradle-dependency-configurations)**

https://medium.com/@gauraw.negi/how-gradle-dependency-configurations-work-underhood-e934906752e5